# ASP.Net One-to-One or Zero Relationship with Identity Models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a relationship from class model Figure to ApplicationUser. ApplicationUser probably have no relation to Figure or exactly single relation to Figure. Figure always have a relationship to ApplicationUser.

I am trying to do this in my code :

**Figure Models**

```
public class Figure
{
    [Key]
    public string FigureId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

**AplicationUser Models**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string Occupation { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public virtual Figure Figure { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Then I got this when running `add-migration Figure` in package manager console :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Lacivi.Models.ApplicationUser'.
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.RegisterSets(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
    at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
    at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
    at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
    at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Lacivi.Models.ApplicationUser'.
```

The last line is colored red. I am wondering that must be the problem, but I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your DbContext class look like? If you inherited from `IdentityDbContext<Lacivi.Models.ApplicationUser>` and added this property

```
public DbSet<Lacivi.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

That's most likely the problem because the `IdentityDbContext<T>` class already contains a property of the same type called Users

Comment: I didn't add anything except those property, `FirstName` `LastName` `BirthDate` etc

Comment: I'm talking about your dbcobtext class. You didn't paste this part of your code. Can you please add it here?

Comment: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Lacivi.Models.Figure> Figures { get; set; }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Lacivi.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }

Comment: That's what I was talking about. Remove the ApplicationUsers property. The IdentityContext class that you inherited already contains property Users.

Comment: then, how can I access the `ApplicationUser` in `AccountController`?

Comment: The same way. Create instance of the ApplicationDbCobtext and call the Users property that already exists in the IdentityContext class you inherited. It's a public property. Just try it.

Comment: Oh yes, I did mistake in `FiguresController` by calling `db.ApplicationUser`, your suggestion to remove ApplicationUsers is make sense. Thanks